# How do I connect AWS Lambda to homemade server?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, aws-lambda

I am looking for some help knowing what to research/look into for connecting an AWS Lambda function to a homemade server.

I am building an Amazon Echo skill that uses AWS Lambda. The end goal is to have the Echo skill get information from my server and contribute to a database sitting on the server. I am using Nginx and Gunicorn to help serve my Flask application.

Are there any tools or concepts I can look into to make this work? Currently, I am kind of lost and am seeing AWS Lambda and my server as two unique, silo-ed entities. But surely this isn't the case!

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build an API on your server. Probably a REST API, or at least some HTTP endpoints on your Flask server that will accept some JSON data in the request. Then your Lambda function will make HTTP requests to your server to interact with it.